# RegExp alternative to negative lookahead match for Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm setting up some conversion funnels on Google Analytics. One is to analyse traffic going from the main site to a secondary promotional site running on a virtual directory (on the same domain though)

I should add, this is a setup form in Google Analytics, I can't using another other code (PHP, JS, C# etc) and it has to be done in one step

So for example something like:

- **/default.aspx** or **/directory/default.aspx** or **/somedirname/default.aspx**
- [to >]
- **/promotion/default.aspx**

In regular expression land, this would be:

- **^/(?!promotion)(.*).aspx**
- [to >]
- **^/promotion/(.*).aspx**

The problem is Google Analytics no longer supports negative lookaheads, so the regexp **^/(?!promotion)(.*).aspx** fails. ([Reference here, first reply](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=0dca2a7bff5384a2))

Is there another way I can do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do a two-step approach (whether that's possible in Analytics, I have no idea, though):

1. Replace unconditionally:
   `/(.*\.aspx)      -->      /promotion/$1`
2. Replace again:
   `/promotion/promotion/(.*)      -->      /promotion/$1`

If all else fails:

```
^/(?:[^p]|p[^r]|pr[^o]|pro[^m]|prom[^o]|promo[^t]|promot[^i]|promoti[^o]|promotio[^n])/(.*)\.aspx
```

Comment: thanks Tomalak, but it can only be done in one step, using only regular expressions :(

Comment: The "all else fails" version did the trick for me... super annoying that (?!...) doesn't work though!