# Stuck on a regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have this currently

```
([\w\-"]+)[ ]+OBJECT-TYPE[^[::=]*]*::=[ ]*\{[ ]*([\w\-"]+) ([\w\-"]+)
```

What it does is search for stuff like this:

```
DATA1 OBJECT-TYPE
SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF ContactInfoEntry
MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
STATUS current
DESCRIPTION
"A table containing Contact Info information"
::= { DATA2  DATA3 }
```

I just had one problem that thought i fixed

```
OBJECT-TYPE[^[::=]*]*::=
```

This was meant to search for any chars after the string "OBJECT-TYPE" that wasnt "::=" until it actualy found "::=" this worked well until i noticed that

```
[^[::=]*]*
```

actualy meant meant : or = and not the excact string "::=" so how do i fix that?

EDIT: If someone is still here so that i dont need to open another question, how do i ignore any and all chars, symbols, numbers, etc between two ".
Example:
 dont ignore this "ignore everything that is in here" dont ignore again "ignore again" etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in this kind of construct:

```
(?:(?!::=).)*
```

To match any character except `::=`.

---

By the way, `[^[::=]*]*` will match any character(s) except `[`, `:`, `=`, `]` and then 0 or more `]`.

---

For the second part, you can use something like this, with some simplification applied:

```
([\w"-]+)[ ]+OBJECT-TYPE(?:"[^"]*"|(?!::=).)*::=[ ]*{[ ]*([\w"-]+) ([\w"-]+)
```

Comment: Is there no other option? I dont like lookaheads they take to much CPU power on large and many files,

Comment: @Vajura I don't like them much either, but no, it would be much much more complex if you use negated classes. You might search 'alternative for negative lookahead', the first one I get is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1537425/1578604).

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "ignore" and "don't ignore"? Regex is about matching and not matching... Maybe you mean to say that `::=` between quotes should not be treated as true `::=`, sort of like a comment?

Comment: Oh yea sorry bad wording, i just meant that everything between commas should be match for the regex expression and yea as you said it should not be treated as a true ::=

Comment: @Vajura Ok, I'm not sure where exactly you want this behaviour, but I have edited my answer so that things within quotes after `OBJECT-TYPE`  are 'ignored'. Let me know whether that works for you or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with (:|=) that will pick one or the other. Not sure if you need to escape : or = though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try negative lookarounds:

`^((?!::=).)*`